# How do I colour a number from a Javascript variable when it hits a certain number, within the Code.org HTML Web Lab?

Tags: javascript, html, code.org

I'm creating a website via the Code.org Web Lab, and I've got a variable within  tags that I'd like to recolour once it hits 100. What code should I use, within HTML or Javascript parts of the page, to achieve this?

This is a new concept to me, adding Javascript to HTML, so I looked it up on Google and Stack Overflow for answers. Every result just talked about either colouring certain words in a paragraph, or saving colours in javascript variables.

Here's the Javascript within the page that contains the variable in question:

```
<script>
      function clickCounter() {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
          if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
          } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
          }
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "People have attempted but failed to help me " + localStorage.clickcount + " times.";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support helping me.";
        }
      }
    </script>
```

And here's the HTML associated with the clicking variable:

```
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button"><b>HELP ME</b></button></p>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

The code itself works perfectly, but I don't have any idea how to colour it once it gets to 100 clicks. If anyone could help me, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add your HTML code?

Comment: All of the page? If not, how much of it?

Comment: All of the relevant information.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that now.

Comment: Alright, I’ve added the HTML you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you did not add the element you want the color to be changed, I'm going to add a `<p>` here.

You can change text color of an element with `.style.color`.
Most CSS styles can be modified with [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

A style applies to 1 HTML element and everything within that particular element as well so, if you apply the color to `<div id="result"></div>`, the whole thing will have its color changed.

To fix that, you have to change the HTML so that you can target the specific part you want to change. Here, I wrapped `localStorage.clickcount` with `<span id="recolor"></span>`.

Then, you can target `recolor` and change its color when `localStorage.clickcount >= 100`.

```
<script>
function clickCounter() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "People have attempted but failed to help me <span id='recolor'>" + localStorage.clickcount + "</span> times.";

    if (localStorage.clickcount >= 100) {
      document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "blue";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support helping me.";
  }
}
</script>


<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button"><b>HELP ME</b></button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: The text to recolour is the number from the variable, in the <script> tags. It’s displayed through the <div> at the bottom.

Comment: @DragonSlayr15001 The answer has been edited to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can maintain a global count variable in your javascript code .
When you click on the button increase it by 1. 
When the count is equal to 100 change the color of the result

```
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
        localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        if(localStorage.clickcount == 100){
           document.getElementById("result").style.color = "red";
           localStorage.clickcount = 0;
        }
    } else {
        localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "People have attempted but failed to help me " + localStorage.clickcount + " times.";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support helping me.";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no need of global variable, because he already have the variable stored in localStorage. He just need to check its value and change the style when hit 100.

Comment: Exactly. Thing is, I don’t know how to change the text color within JavaScript... If you could tell me, that’d be great!

Comment: document.getElementById("result").style.color = "red";        This is how you can change the textcolor

Comment: And yes you don't need that global variable . I changed that for you